# How to efficiently read environment parameters from file, to be used with exec

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables, exec, command-line-arguments

I want to be able to save to file the argv and environ of a process, and than, at a later time, to be able to `fork` and `exec`
using the parameters that are saved to file.

The only design I could think of, is to write to file the list of parameters as a long string, but then I need to convert it from string to an array of strings, which is possible but very cumbersome.

Can anyone think of a better way to do it?

Comment: do you need the file to be portable between architectures?

Comment: No, no need for portability

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for the file format

- the first line is a decimal number N which is equal to `argc`
- the next N lines are the `argv` strings, one string per line
- then there's another decimal number M which is equal to the number of environment strings
- the next M lines are the environment strings, one string per line

To read the file back into memory

- read the first line with `getline` and convert the number with `sscanf`
- `malloc` an array of N+1 pointers
- read the next N lines using `getline`, storing the pointer in the `argv` array
- put a NULL pointer at the end of the `argv` array
- read the next line with `getline` and convert the number with `sscanf`
- `malloc` an array of M+1 pointers
- read the next M lines using `getline`, storing the pointer in the `env` array
- put a NULL pointer at the end of the `env` array

There are two things to keep in mind when using `getline`. First, it will automatically `malloc` the memory for the string. Second, it puts the newline at the end of the string, so you have to remove it.

Sample code that reads the `argv` strings using `getline`

```
int N = 5;
char **argv = malloc( (N + 1) * sizeof(char *) );

char *line;
size_t linecap, length;

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    line = NULL;            // request that getline allocate memory
    linecap = 0;
    if ( (length = getline( &line, &linecap, fp )) <= 0 )
        exit( 1 );          // file ended prematurely

    line[length-1] = '\0';  // get rid of the pesky newline
    argv[i] = line;
}

argv[N] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this problem is by writing a binary file with the following structure:

```
begin file header:

  0x00 :: 0x03 [  4 bytes] number of entries

for each entry n at offset 0x04 + n * 4:

  0x00 :: 0x03 [  4 bytes] string length of entry (including terminating \0)

end file header
```

after the header, write all entries as strings to the file, including the terminating `\0` byte.

To read this file, I would use `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose` to read the array of offsets from the file, and then I would `mmap` the file, and transform the array of offsets to an array of pointers into the mmapped region.

**Portability Note:**

If you want to be able to read the file on one architecture and read it on a different one, you will need to

- make sure you use fixed width datatypes (e.g. `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`)
- decide on a byte order to avoid endianness issues.

so, say, if you wanted to write a `uint32_t` to a file, without endianness issues you could use

```
void
write_uint32 (FILE *f, uint32_t v)
{
  unsigned char out[4] = { 0 };
  out[0] = v & 0xff; v >>= 8;
  out[1] = v & 0xff; v >>= 8;
  out[2] = v & 0xff; v >>= 8;
  out[3] = v
  fwrite(out, 1, sizeof(out), f);
}
```

and to read the same value

```
uint32_t
read_uint32 (FILE *f)
{
  unsigned char in[4] = { 0 }
  fread(in, 1, sizeof(in), f);
  return in[3] << 24 | in[2] << 16 | in[1] << 8 | in[0];
}
```

Comment: The mmap solution seems very elegant, but it is the first time I encounter it so I should probably hit the books before asking any further questions...

Comment: This is the part that I find unclear: "and then I would `mmap` the file, and transform the array of offsets to an array of pointers into the mmapped region." How exactly do I do it?

Comment: @yaloner if you have an array of offsets into a file, and then `mmap` said file, each offset into the file can be mapped to a pointer into the mmapped region by adding the base address to the region that is returned by mmap.

Comment: still not sure I understand the process of getting a char** as a result. Do you happen to have an example?

Comment: I don't understand your question - transforming an array of `long` of offsets into a file to an array of `char*` of pointers into a memory region should be trivial? pseudocode `for i = 0 to max: chars[i] = longs[i] + base`